# changed position of element on scroll()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Have the following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hpXL4/202/

Trying to get it to work, but can't seem to? Looking to basically change the position of the element after scrolling X height.

```
var cta = $("#bottomcta");
cta.on("scroll", function(e) { 
  if (this.scrollTop > 50) {
    cta.addClass("fixed");
  } 
    else {
    cta.removeClass("fixed");
  }
});
```

Comment: The scroll event occurs on the `window` object, not on a specific DOM element; what you want to use is `$(window).on('scroll', …)` And you should probably read http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/ too, before you create something that might be a huge performance drag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necessary to use the Windows elements. Representative link below.... :)

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hpXL4/203/)

```
var cta = $(window);
cta.on("scroll", function(e) { 
  if (cta.scrollTop() > 50) {
    $("#bottomcta").addClass("fixed");
  } 
    else {
    $("#bottomcta").removeClass("fixed");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are adding or removing a the class every time the scroll function in called. This could result in adding or removing the class "fixed" hundred of times. I don't know if this will fix your problem but I would use

```html
cta.hasClass("fixed");
```

to check if the class has already been applied to the element before you try adding it.